# Designing an SQL Database where multiple tables use the same model

Tags: c#, postgresql, database-design, repository-pattern

**Background**

I am trying to design a PostgreSQL database that will store trade records from cryptocurrency exchanges. I have a single `Trade` model in my client, but would like to split the trades into their own tables based on the symbol they represent. The symbols that are available are deduced at runtime, and trades from the exchange each have their own Id sequence starting at 0.

For example, say I want to cache trades from Binance. My client would call their API, see that (some) of the symbols available on the platform are `BTCUSDT`, `ETHUSDT`, and `ETHBTC`, and if those symbols aren't already in the `bn.Symbols` table, it would insert them, as well as create a new table `bn.Trades-SYMBOLNAME`.

The tech stack I am using is .NET Core 3 with Dapper and PostgreSQL.

**The issue**

I have seen several posts detailing how to write a procedure or function that creates a table with a provided variable as the name, and [a common sentiment seems to be that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/941284/9285560) [this is a poor design](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11423855/9285560).

In addition to this negative sentiment, my client is using the Repository and Unit of Work Patterns, and the `TradeRepository` is interfaced in a way that defines a `GetById(long)` method, so I cannot specify which symbol I want the repository to target, nor can I specify the symbol in the repository functions, without resorting to some dirty tricks.

A simple solution would be to store all trades in the same table, have a foreign key column for `Symbol`, and create a unique composite index for the `Id` and `Symbol` columns. However, I am hesitant to do this, because I will eventually be storing over a billion trades, and this approach also still causes issues with my current Repository pattern design.

Is there a better way to approach this?

**Code**

Here is some code showing how my models are currently configured:

```
public abstract class EntityBase : IEntity
{

  #region Properties

  public long Id
  {
     get;
     set;
  }

  #endregion

}

public class Symbol : EntityBase
{

  #region Data Members

  private long _baseAssetId;
  private long _quoteAssetId;

  #endregion

  #region Properties

  public string Name
  {
     get;
     set;
  }

  public long BaseAssetId
  {
     get
     {
        if( BaseAsset != null )
           return _baseAssetId = BaseAsset.Id;

        return _baseAssetId;
     }
     set => _baseAssetId = value;
  }

  public int BaseAssetPrecision
  {
     get;
     set;
  }

  public long QuoteAssetId
  {
     get
     {
        if( QuoteAsset != null )
           return _quoteAssetId = QuoteAsset.Id;

        return _quoteAssetId;
     }
     set => _quoteAssetId = value;
  }

  public int QuoteAssetPrecision
  {
     get;
     set;
  }

  #endregion

  #region Navigation Properties

  public virtual Asset BaseAsset
  {
     get;
     set;
  }

  public virtual Asset QuoteAsset
  {
     get;
     set;
  }

  #endregion

}

public class Trade : EntityBase
{

  #region Properties

  public decimal Price
  {
     get;
     set;
  }

  public decimal Quantity
  {
     get;
     set;
  }

  public decimal QuoteQuantity
  {
     get;
     set;
  }

  public long Timestamp
  {
     get;
     set;
  }

  public bool IsBuyer
  {
     get;
     set;
  }

  public DateTime Time
  {
     get => Timestamp.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
  }

  #endregion

}
```

Here is how all repositories are interfaced:

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> : IDisposable
  where TEntity : IEntity, new()
{

  Task AddAsync( TEntity entity, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default );
  Task<TEntity> GetByIdAsync( long id, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default );
  Task<bool> RemoveAsync( TEntity entity, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default );
  Task<bool> UpdateAsync( TEntity entity, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default );

}
```

And here is how the UnitOfWork is interfaced:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{

  #region Properties

  Guid Id
  {
     get;
  }

  IDbConnection Connection
  {
     get;
  }

  IDbTransaction Transaction
  {
     get;
  }

  #endregion

  #region Repositories

  IAssetRepository Assets
  {
     get;
  }

  ITradeRepository Trades
  {
     get;
  }

  ISymbolRepository Symbols
  {
     get;
  }

  #endregion

  #region Public Methods

  void Begin();
  void Commit();
  void Rollback();

  #endregion

}
```

Comment: The simple solution you describe seems the natural way to do this. What are the issues that causes with you current Repository pattern design? Re: storing billions of records - that comes down to how the database is optimised, indexed, tuned, partitioned etc, not your repository/model design.

Comment: @Polyfun The problem is that the repository pattern designates `GetById(long id)`. Ideally, this method would be able to select a trade with the specified Id and symbol, and each symbol has its own Id numbering. If I use the same table, I'd have to either include a redundant auto-numbered Id column to support this method and rename the Trade model's Id column to `TradeId`, or block off the method completely and create a new method that does support querying by symbol. I suppose that's just a nit at this point though.

Comment: When you "get", you have to include all the fields that form the primary key; in your case you have a compound key of id and symbol, so you have to use both in your get method. There is nothing in the standard repository pattern that prevents this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A simple solution would be to store all trades in the same table, have a foreign key column for Symbol, and create a unique composite index for the Id and Symbol columns. However, I am hesitant to do this, because I will eventually be storing over a billion trades, and this approach also still causes issues with my current Repository pattern design.

This is the answer. Use a single table and differentiate with your symbol column. The disadvantages of seperating them out are performance (because of the joins mostly) and "normalisation" because of the duplication in tables that are pretty much identical